# AMPscript syntax

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this piece of AMPscript which shows different preheaders based on language. 
Except two, GB and JP, all of the others show the relevant preheader.
The data extension has the right value and it works perfectly fine for the rest of the countries so I'm a bit lost

```
        %%[  

    var @CustomerID,@cc,@lang,@prefCountry,@code,@campaign,@preheader

    set @CustomerID = [SubscriberKey]
    set @lang = Lookup("Recipients","language","CustomerID",@CustomerID)
    set @prefCountry = Lookup("Recipients","preferredcountryid","CustomerID",@CustomerID)
    set @cc = Lookup("Recipients","language","CustomerID",@CustomerID)
    set @campaign = concat(emailname_,@cc)
    set @code = concat(@campaign,-1)
    set @preheader = Lookup("autoBanner_Segmentation","preHeader_default","email_code",@code)


    %%[ /*UK targeting start*/
    if ((@lang=='en' and (@prefcountry==1 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='au' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==1)) then 

    set @cc = 'gb'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*AU targeting start*/
    elseif ((@lang=='au' and (@prefcountry==27 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==27) or (@prefcountry==29)) then 

    set @cc = 'au'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*US targeting*/
    elseif ((@lang=='us' and (@prefcountry==18 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==18)) then 

    set @cc = 'us'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*NZ targeting*/
    elseif ((@lang=='nz' and (@prefcountry==35 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='us') and @prefcountry==35) or (@prefcountry==38)) then 

    set @cc = 'nz'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*DE targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='de') then 

    set @cc = 'de'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*DA/DK targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='da') then 

    set @cc = 'da'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*ES targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='es') then 

    set @cc = 'es'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*FR targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='fr') then 

    set @cc = 'fr'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*IT targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='it') then 

    set @cc = 'it'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*JP targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='ja') then 

    set @cc = 'jp'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*NL targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='nl') then 

    set @cc = 'nl'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*RU targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='ru') then 

    set @cc = 'ru'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*SV targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='sv') then 

    set @cc = 'sv'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*ZH targeting*/
    elseif (@lang=='zh') then 

    set @cc = 'zh'
    ]%%

    %%[ /*ROW*/
    else 

    set @cc = 'en'
    ]%%

    %%[endif]%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue was that you were appending the `@cc` variable before your conditional if statements, meaning that the `@code` you used in your lookup may not exist in the DE, causing it to return empty.

Try rearranging it like this:

```
    %%[  

var @CustomerID,@cc,@lang,@prefCountry,@code,@campaign,@preheader

set @CustomerID = [SubscriberKey]
set @lang = Lookup("Recipients","language","CustomerID",@CustomerID)
set @prefCountry = Lookup("Recipients","preferredcountryid","CustomerID",@CustomerID)
set @cc = Lookup("Recipients","language","CustomerID",@CustomerID)

%%[ /*UK targeting start*/
if ((@lang=='en' and (@prefcountry==1 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='au' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==1)) then 

set @cc = 'gb'
]%%

%%[ /*AU targeting start*/
elseif ((@lang=='au' and (@prefcountry==27 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='us' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==27) or (@prefcountry==29)) then 

set @cc = 'au'
]%%

%%[ /*US targeting*/
elseif ((@lang=='us' and (@prefcountry==18 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='nz') and @prefcountry==18)) then 

set @cc = 'us'
]%%

%%[ /*NZ targeting*/
elseif ((@lang=='nz' and (@prefcountry==35 or empty(@prefcountry))) or ((@lang=='au' or @lang=='en' or @lang=='us') and @prefcountry==35) or (@prefcountry==38)) then 

set @cc = 'nz'

endif

set @campaign = concat(emailname_,@cc)
set @code = concat(@campaign,-1)
set @preheader = Lookup("autoBanner_Segmentation","preHeader_default","email_code",@code)
]%%
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked

Comment: its still confusing for me why did it show fine for the rest of the languages?

Comment: Likely because most of them already had the language of the cc you are looking to utilize. E.g. NZ had a language of `nz` (which is what you set as default in top | cc = lang) so it was able to match, where the GB one had a lang of `en` which would not match.

Comment: makes perfect sense now, thank again